# check which button got clicked javafx

Tags: java, button, fxml, javafx-11

can anyone help, I'm making a program to buy credit. Does anyone know how to confirm the nominal number button has been clicked before the transaction button?

[image]

My program has an error when I haven't clicked the nominal button but the transaction is successful what I want is if I haven't clicked the nominal number button, the "choose nominal" alert appears

```
@FXML
private Button fivethsnd;
@FXML
private Button transaction;

static String noHP;
ArrayList<String[]> data = new File().baca();

// method button fivethsnd
   public int fivethousand(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
    Node node = (Node) mouseEvent.getTarget();
    String tosrtingfivethousand = fivethsnd.getText();
    System.out.println(tosrtingfivethousand);
    return 1;
}



//method transaction

public void Transaction(MouseEvent event)throws IOException {
    Alert settransaction = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
    settransaction.setTitle("Something Wrong");
    settransaction.setHeaderText(null);
    
    //call the fivethousand method to check the button has been clicked
    if (fivethousand(event)==1){
        String[] sellpulses = new String[2];
        noHP=numberhp.getText();
        String digitfirst = "081";
        String digit = noHP.substring(0,3);
        boolean isNumeric = noHP.chars().allMatch(Character::isDigit);
        System.out.println("digit: "+digit);
        System.out.println(noHP);
        if (noHP.length() == 12 || noHP.length() == 13) {
            if (isNumeric) {
                if (digit.equals(digitfirst)){
                    sellpulses[0]=numberhp.getText();
                    sellpulses[1]= fivethsnd.getText();
                    data.add(sellpulses);
                    new File().simpan(data); // save to txt file

                }
                else {
                    settransaction.setContentText("The first 3 digits must be 081");
                    settransaction.showAndWait();

                }
            } else {
                settransaction.setContentText("Mobile number must be a number");
                settransaction.showAndWait();

            }
        } else {
            settransaction.setContentText("Nomor HP tidak valid");
            settransaction.showAndWait();

        }
    }else if (limaribu(event)!=1){
        settransaction.setContentText("choose nominal first"); // allert when nominal not clicked
        settransaction.showAndWait();

    }



}
```

Comment: Please use english names and strings (at least in your question) to make it easier to reason about your code

Comment: I would declare a class member variable that would initially have no value and would assign it the value of the _nominal_ button that was clicked (for example `10.000`). Then when the _transaction_ button is clicked, check whether the class member variable has a valid value. If it does, perform the transaction and clear the variable's value. If it doesn't, display the `Alert`. By the way, if you use [java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) it will be easier for me to understand your code.